# How to list columns name from any SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

Using SQL Alchemy, I'd like to know if it's possible to get a list of all columns from any SQL query.

For example, if I call this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

I would need all the results, but also a list of all the columns from the table `users`.

I know I could hit the table Informations Schema, but my problem also affect any kind of query, like :

```
SELECT u.*, f.name, f.size FROM users u LEFT JOIN files f ON f.user_id = u.id;
```

I saw this option from SQL Alchemy, `[column_description][1]`, but I don't know if it works only for an ORM style ; I am using a non ORM style (I will write directly the queries).

Comment: General best practice in database apps in never use `Select *` as you know which fields you want as you have to know how to process them and then when the db is altered by adding fields it does not affect your code, also the database filed names are unlikely to be what your users call the information . So I would ask what is the user requirement you are trying to develop here.

Comment: I'm playing to build an alternative to PhpMyAdmin. I can't control what will be written in queries, and I'm pretty sure this kind of query will be written more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ResultProxy.keys()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy.keys):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM users;"
res_proxy = session.execute(sql)
column_names = res_proxy.keys()
```

*However, I agree with Mark that one should not use `SELECT *` as a general rule.*

Comment: Thanks for your tip. As for `SELECT *`, see my comment after his ;)

Comment: Saw the comment, have no idea what PhpMyAdmin is and how it works though :). I am sure you have good reason. Good luck with the project!